# Jquery / Javascript change form action based on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form like this

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action='' name='myform' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='cars'>
    <button action='submit'>Search Cars</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is change the form action to be something like `action='http://www.mysite.com/<cars_value>.html'>` based on whatever is filled into the input field (which is populated by autocomplete).

Is there an easy way of doing this?  I can do it with a `<select>` easily enough but the customer wants an input field instead!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this, you will need to add ids to items. One thing you might want to do is validate the users input.

**HTML**

```
<form action='' name='myform' id="myform" method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='cars' id="cars">
  <button action='submit'>Search Cars</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
  var car = $('#cars').val();
  $(this).attr('action', "http://www.mysite.com/" + car + ".html");
});
```

EDIT:
It is best to be javascript at bottom of page;

**FULL**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action='' name='myform' id="myform" method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='cars' id="cars">
    <button action='submit'>Search Cars</button>
  </form>
  <script src="path-to-jquery"></script>
  <script>
  // Shorthand for $(document).ready();
  $(function() {
   $('#myform').submit(function(){
     var car = $('#cars').val();
     $(this).attr('action', "http://www.mysite.com/" + car + ".html");
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers for that, that looks like what I was thinking of.   Sorry bit new to jquery / js - where does that go in the code (the jquery bit) and does it need to go inside a <script></script> at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    this.action = 'http://mysite.com/<xyz>.html';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - How would <xyx> be gathered from the form though? i.e. if the user types in Ferrari or Aston Martin or Jaguar for instance?

Comment: In that case, replace `<xyz>` with `$('#myInputField').val()` - where `myInputField` is the `ID` of the field whose value you need in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from the input field and populate the xyz value.. Try this

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {

    var value = $('input[type="text"]').val(); 

    this.action = 'http://mysite.com/' + value + '.html';
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your input, and then update the action. Return true if you want to form to submit after changing the value, or false if these are separate buttons.

```
<button onclick="changeVal($('input').val()">change value</button>
<script>
    function changeVal(value){
    $("form").attr("action",'http://mysite.com/'+value+'.html');
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Be careful doing things like this, as if you use this solution you will be opening yourself up to javascript injection attacks. You'll want to "scrub" your input before injecting it into your form.

Comment: thanks, for the advice on security, I'd thought of that for all my php inputs - so will do the same for the JS side.  Cheers