# url problems with javascript output

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

<del>document.getElementById('f_widget_job_search').action =("http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-"+q+"&l"+l+"?"+"pshid=55414&ssty=2"+"&cflg=r&jbd=doors.jobamatic.com&clip=38.98.177.132");</del>

I am trying to get this url that is based on a few form values that are pulled in via variables to be the action of a form, with no luck... it seems that I am having trouble with #1 the variable based portion of the url monster being included twice like this:

http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-Billing&l-?l=&q=Billing

or

if i remove the question mark from the url i get:

http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-Select%20all%20that%20apply...&l-pshid=55414&ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=doors.jobamatic.com&clip=38.98.177.132?l=&q=Select+all+that+apply...

see how that last bit just keeps getting repeated?

I am fairly new to javascript and I know that the ? is the thing that is screwing me up, but I need it in the url to make it work, so i guess what i need to know is how to write this in such a way as to include the question mark and not have it screw up the way the url is being output.

Thank you so much in advance, I have been trying to figure this out for hours.

*edit*

```
function earl() {
var q=document.f_widget_job_search.q.value;
var l=document.f_widget_job_search.l.value;

document.getElementById('f_widget_job_search').action;
document.getElementById('f_widget_job_search').action = ("http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-"+q+"&l-"+l+"\?pshid=55414&ssty=2"+"&cflg=r"+"&jbd=doors.jobamatic.com"+"&clip=38.98.177.132");
}

<form id="f_widget_job_search" name="f_widget_job_search" class="search_form" onSubmit="javascript:earl()">
   <select id="q" name="q">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
   </select>
   <input id="l" name="l" type="text">
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567953/jquery-javascript-change-form-action-based-on-input-field

Comment: @kol , I am not having a problem with the url being output, it's being put together correctly, except the question mark is making weird things happen as far as i can tell.

Comment: Can you post the javascript that pulls the form values?

Comment: I will @kehrk i will edit my post