# JS - Create Redirect URL String from Form Answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

Our site is making the switch to Typeform from FormAssembly for our application form, but it's crucial for us to be able to customize the form's "redirect on completion" URLs based on how the user answers the form. FormAssembly offers that feature but I don't think Typeform does, and without a workaround it will break all our of our Analytics goal conversion reports and business intelligence data. It's really really important for us to maintain this data and the conversion URLs.

Maybe there's a Javascript/jQuery/PHP way of accomplishing in Typeform what we've been doing with FormAssembly (see below)? Or another workaround whatsoever? Is it even possible to do this? Hopefully someone can offer a bit of advice ...

Here's our current redirect on completion URL with the FormAssembly form:
/application-complete?details=**[NAcert]**

The "NAcert" part of that string is a calculated value with four possible values based on how the user answers two questions in our form :

1. NAcert = Answer to Citizenship question is "United States" or "Canada" ; and the answer to Certified question is "Yes"
2. NAnot = Answer to Citizenship question is "United States" or "Canada" ; and the answer to Certified question is "No"
3. OTHcert = Answer to Citizenship is not "United States" or "Canada" ; and answer to Certified question is "Yes"
4. OTHnot = Answer to Citizenship is not "United States" or "Canada" ; and answer to Certified question is "No"

While Typeform offers hidden fields but no way to populate them from other form answers, especially with the above conditional rules for values. Similarly, it lets you pass field values to redirect URL, but only straight up values again without any conditionals ...

edit: the linked solutions that try to adjust  action won't work for Typeform

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery / Javascript change form action based on input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567953/jquery-javascript-change-form-action-based-on-input-field)

Comment: no, unfortunately that doesn't work because there's no control of the <form> element, that form doesn't seem to use <form> when i view its source, it's coded differently - see https://andriyfp.typeform.com/to/VkoSsD

Answer (score 2):

Marcel from Typeform here.

Although not ideal, you can use the score variable in the calculator and multiple thank you screens with different redirect URLs to accomplish your goal. You can check out this [form](https://marcel5.typeform.com/to/ll3ThK) (API definition [here](https://api.typeform.com/forms/ll3ThK)) to see what I mean, feel free to ask for clarifications if needed.

In this example each of the thank you screens has different texts, but you could just have the same content and only modify the redirect button URL to make them look identical for your respondents.

We're currently working on supporting multiple variables in forms, and also having different types in them (so not only numerical values but also strings in this case), so hopefully by the time we release this (early next year according to our plan), this should be much easier. Hope my "hack" helps in the meantime, and thanks for using our product!

PS:  My hacky solution won't work if you're already using the score variable in your form.

Comment: Wow, thanks Marcel for following up so quickly!! That definitely looks like it's on the way to a solution, but we need the user to auto redirect (as opposed to after button click). I tried the calculator before for this but it didn't work for me. Can you touch base with me at mishchenko at gmail.com ?

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid that's another downside of my solution...As I said, it was quite hacky :P If having your customers click on the redirect button is definitely a no-go for you, then I'm afraid you'll have to wait until we release support for multiple variables

Comment: oh that's really disappointing. do you think there's nothing else we can do - for example somehow use our own JS to change the value of a hidden typeform field which would then be passed into the redirect URL in the typeform UI redirect URL settings? (this can already be done with normal response values ie email address, but as you know i'm trying to make a new calculated value for this use case)

and re: the multiple variables, is 2020 the absolute earliest for that (even for beta?). launching this week and really don't want to screw up our analytics data with incorrect form completion URLs

Comment: another idea is some code for your example to auto press that second button ("redirect me" in your form); or the first one ("submit")? just to reduce friction for the user...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use the submit event to change the action value of the form.

```
function changeAction(e) {
  var NAcert = 'NAcert' // insert code to set this value
  e.target.action = '/application-complete?details=' + NAcert
}
myForm.addEventListener("submit", changeAction);
```

Obviously, if you're using jQuery you can use that method of doing the exactly the same thing. Also, I didn't actually test this code, but hopefully you get the idea.